# A new index for each container?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I am currently running a test environment to try gelf logging driver to monitor container logs with a single node stack and so far it worked well. But I need to make some changes and I'm pretty new to this so I need some help. Each container's logs are being sent to a single index which is "logstash*", I want seperate indexes for each container preferebly using gelf logging driver. If this has a solution through another driver I'm open to hear that as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should share logstash pipeline configs and try explain your question with example. also creating two many indices is not healthy for elasticsearch. maybe you should explain why you are need an indices per container

Comment: I found the solution for this if anyone else gets stuck at this,

add a tag option when creating your container with the other logging driver options you have.
then change your logstash.conf output:

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "%{tag}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
    }
}